# com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar: problem with right and thumb image

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar, rangeseekbar

I use in my android app with Kotlin the following library "com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar" to set the price of product in slider. Here's the following code :

```
<com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    app:min_value="0"
    app:max_value="100"
    app:bar_color="@color/lightGreyTwo"
    app:bar_highlight_color="@color/honey"
    app:data_type="_integer"
    app:right_thumb_image="@drawable/circle"
    app:left_thumb_image="@drawable/circle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewPrice" />
```

And the following is circle.xml in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="@color/honey" android:width="8dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <size android:width="22dp" android:height="22dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But, I get the following error :

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #132: Binary XML
>   file line #132: Error inflating class
>   com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #132: Binary XML file line #132: Error inflating class com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #132: Error inflating class com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar

My objective is to set a slider as the following picture 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using drawable as an app:left_thumb_image="".
but, in BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar support image format icon (.png , etc..) in app:left_thumb_image="" so, replace your drawable icon to .png icon.